Ending Textbox when the user type ESC in ncurses with Python
General overview
In a curses wrapper, I have a main stdscr. If I press : then I enter in a specific mode where I can type text inside a curses.textpad.Textbox.
In my following MWE it work fine until this state. But the goal now is to break the the typing mode if the user type ESC.
Minimal working example
import curses
import curses.textpad

def enteringExMode(stdscr):
    curses.curs_set(1)  # Show cursor

    editwin = curses.newwin(0, 0, 0, 0)
    editwin.clear()

    # Edition in textzone
    tb = curses.textpad.Textbox(editwin)
    tb.edit()

    # Get the writen text
    user_text = tb.gather()


def main(stdscr):
    while True:
        stdscr.clear()
        key = stdscr.get_wch()
        if key == ":":
            enteringExMode(stdscr)

curses.wrapper(main)

The question
So how to make the typing mode take end if the user type ESC?

This question is similar to: Python curses: Make enter key terminate Textbox?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  The particular choice of ESC versus enter is irrelevant.
